# Using SSJS to report on email sends using the Single Send ID as a URL parameter

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs, cloudpage

Im looking to set up an API that retrives all the email send stats eg. Open Rate, Click rate, Unsubscribes etc...

I have set this up before but cannot remember how unfortunately.
It would return a JSON object that I would then pass into google sheets that would feed to an automated Data(now Looker) Studio Dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a JSON return, you would have to build your own API endpoint to accept this in via a Code Resource. From there you would use either the **[Core function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_sendTrackingRetrieve.html)** or WSProxy via **[Send](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/send.html)** object to retrieve via the Job ID and then pass the result back as response. As a note, Core limits to max of 2500 returned (which should be no problem if only returning a single job), where WSProxy can go beyond that limitation.

SSJS Core:

```
var sendTracking = Send.Tracking.Retrieve({Property:"SendID",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:12345});
```

SSJS WSProxy: (example taken from **[@AdamSpriggs blog](https://sprignaturemoves.com/retrieving-and-storing-aggregated-send-data/)**.)

```html
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("core","1");
var debug = false;

try {

    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    // DESCRIBE - SEND
    // https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/send.htm
    var sendDescribe = prox.describe("Send");
    var sendCols0 = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < sendDescribe.Results[0].Properties.length; i++) {

      if (sendDescribe.Results[0].Properties[i].IsRetrievable) {
        sendCols0.push(sendDescribe.Results[0].Properties[i].Name);
      }
    }

    var sendObj = "Send";
    var sendCols = sendCols0;

    // var filterDate0 = new Date();
    // filterDate0 = filterDate0.setMinutes(0);
    // filterDate0 = filterDate0.setSeconds(0);
    // filterDate0 = filterDate0.setMilliseconds(0);
    // filterDate0 = filterDate0.setHours(0);

    // var filterDate = DateTime.SystemDateToLocalDate(filterDate0);
    // filterDate.setDate(filterDate.getDate() - 30);

    // if (debug) {
    //  Write("<br><br>filterDate: " + filterDate);
    // }

    // sendFilter = {Property: "SendDate", SimpleOperator: "greaterThan", Value: filterDate};

    var sendFilter = {Property: "ID", SimpleOperator: "greaterThan", Value: 0};
    var moreRows = true;
    var reqID = null;

    while (moreRows) {

        moreRows = false;

        var sendRows = reqID == null ? prox.retrieve(sendObj, sendCols0, sendFilter) : prox.getNextBatch(sendObj, reqID);

        if (sendRows != null) {

            moreRows = sendRows.HasMoreRows;
            reqID = sendRows.RequestID;

            if (sendRows && sendRows.Results) {

                for (var i=0; i < sendRows.Results.length; i++) {

                    var row = {};
                    row.ID = sendRows.Results[i].ID;
                    row.PartnerKey = sendRows.Results[i].PartnerKey;
                    row.CreatedDate = sendRows.Results[i].CreatedDate;
                    row.ModifiedDate = sendRows.Results[i].ModifiedDate;
                    row.Client_ID = sendRows.Results[i].Client.ID;
                    row.Client_PartnerClientKey = sendRows.Results[i].Client.PartnerClientKey;
                    row.Email_ID = sendRows.Results[i].Email.ID;
                    row.Email_PartnerKey = sendRows.Results[i].Email.PartnerKey;
                    row.SendDate = sendRows.Results[i].SendDate;
                    row.FromAddress = sendRows.Results[i].FromAddress;
                    row.FromName = sendRows.Results[i].FromName;
                    row.Duplicates = sendRows.Results[i].Duplicates;
                    row.InvalidAddresses = sendRows.Results[i].InvalidAddresses;
                    row.ExistingUndeliverables = sendRows.Results[i].ExistingUndeliverables;
                    row.ExistingUnsubscribes = sendRows.Results[i].ExistingUnsubscribes;
                    row.HardBounces = sendRows.Results[i].HardBounces;
                    row.SoftBounces = sendRows.Results[i].SoftBounces;
                    row.OtherBounces = sendRows.Results[i].OtherBounces;
                    row.ForwardedEmails = sendRows.Results[i].ForwardedEmails;
                    row.UniqueClicks = sendRows.Results[i].UniqueClicks;
                    row.UniqueOpens = sendRows.Results[i].UniqueOpens;
                    row.NumberSent = sendRows.Results[i].NumberSent;
                    row.NumberDelivered = sendRows.Results[i].NumberDelivered;
                    row.NumberTargeted = sendRows.Results[i].NumberTargeted;
                    row.NumberErrored = sendRows.Results[i].NumberErrored;
                    row.NumberExcluded = sendRows.Results[i].NumberExcluded;
                    row.Unsubscribes = sendRows.Results[i].Unsubscribes;
                    row.MissingAddresses = sendRows.Results[i].MissingAddresses;
                    row.Subject = sendRows.Results[i].Subject;
                    row.PreviewURL = sendRows.Results[i].PreviewURL;
                    row.SentDate = sendRows.Results[i].SentDate;
                    row.EmailName = sendRows.Results[i].EmailName;
                    row.Status = sendRows.Results[i].Status;
                    row.IsMultipart = sendRows.Results[i].IsMultipart;
                    row.SendLimit = sendRows.Results[i].SendLimit;
                    row.SendWindowOpen = new Date(sendRows.Results[i].SendWindowOpen).getFullYear() > 2000 ? sendRows.Results[i].SendWindowOpen : null ;
                    row.SendWindowClose = new Date(sendRows.Results[i].SendWindowClose).getFullYear() > 2000 ? sendRows.Results[i].SendWindowClose : null ;
                    row.IsAlwaysOn = sendRows.Results[i].IsAlwaysOn;
                    row.Additional = sendRows.Results[i].Additional;
                    row.BCCEmail = sendRows.Results[i].BCCEmail;

                    if (sendRows.Results[i].EmailSendDefinition != null ) {
                      row.EmailSendDefinition_ObjectID = sendRows.Results[i].EmailSendDefinition.ObjectID;
                      row.EmailSendDefinition_CustomerKey = sendRows.Results[i].EmailSendDefinition.CustomerKey;
                    }

                    row.UpdatedDate = new Date();

                    var de = DataExtension.Init("Send"); /* external key of target data extension */
                    var rowsAddedUpdated = 0;

                    try {

                      rowsAddedUpdated = de.Rows.Add(row);

                    } catch (e) {

                      if (debug) {
                        Write("<br><br>e: " + Stringify(e));
                      }

                      try {

                        rowsAddedUpdated = de.Rows.Update(row, ['ID'], [sendRows.Results[i].ID]);

                      } catch(e2) {

                        if (debug) {
                         Write("<br>e2: " + Stringify(e2));
                        }

                      }
                    }

                    if (debug) {
                     Write("<br>rowsAddedUpdated: " + rowsAddedUpdated);
                    }


                } // for-loop

            } // row results


        }

    }


} catch (e) {

  if (debug) {
    Platform.Response.Write("<br><br>e: " + Stringify(e));
  }

}
</script>
```